# Get total Car sessions SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table Transactions with id, type, guest_id, timestamp.

I want to get the total Car sessions for the last two months. (assuming all transactions with type 'Car' within the same hour from the same guest constitute 1 session).
I tried

```
SELECT  
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)::int
        FROM transactions t
        WHERE t.type = 'Car'
        AND t.timestamp  <= gs + '1 hour'::interval
          AND t.timestamp > gs
        group by t.guest_id
    ) AS count
    FROM generate_series('2022-11-17 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2023-01-17 23:59:59'::timestamp, '1 hour'::interval) AS gs        
    ORDER BY gs.date ASC
```

but I get an error ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

How do I go about this ?

Comment: Can you share some data and table definition

Comment: Why are you casting counts to int?

Answer (score 0):

try in this way

```
SELECT  
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM transactions t
        WHERE t.type = 'Car'
        AND t.timestamp  <= gs + '1 hour'::interval
          AND t.timestamp > gs
    ) AS count
    FROM generate_series('2022-11-17 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2023-01-17 23:59:59'::timestamp, '1 hour'::interval) AS gs        
    ORDER BY gs.date ASC
```

Comment: I want to return just a single value, the total_sessions.

Comment: starting from this comment: "(assuming all transactions with type 'Car' within the same hour from the same guest constitute 1 session)", you can try to add some group by value, probabily you have to group in this way:

group by hour(gs.date),"guest field"
and then select:
hour(gs.date),"guest field",count(id) as total_sessions

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want a join of your table and the generated series

```
    SELECT t.guest_id, gs.dt, COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM transactions t
    JOIN generate_series('2022-11-17 00:00:00'::timestamp, '2023-01-17 23:59:59'::timestamp, '1 hour'::interval) AS gs(dt) 
      ON t.timestamp  <= gs.dt + '1 hour'::interval
        AND t.timestamp > gs.dt
    WHERE t.type = 'Car'
    GROUP BY t.guest_id, gs.dt
    ORDER BY t.guest_id, gs.dt
```